# I am getting a 403 error and need to know to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Node.js and am learning about sessions for the first time. I was following a video on sessions and am getting a 403 error when I try to signup using localhost:3000/signup. I am passing {"username": "sebastian", "password": "password"} to the signup API. My app.js auth is giving me a 403 error and I don't know why. can you please help? I really need help fast.

app.js

```
 var express = require('express');
    var User = require('../models/user')

    var router = express.Router();
    router.use(express.json())

    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     res.send('respond with a resource');
   });

   router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .then((user) => {
      if(user != null) {
        var err = new Error('User ' + req.body.username + ' already exists!');
        err.status = 403;
        next(err);
      }
      else {
        return User.create({
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password});
      }
    })
    .then((user) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({status: 'Registration Successful!', user: user});
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
  
  router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  
    if(!req.session.user) {
      var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
      
      if (!authHeader) {
        var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      }
    
      var auth = new Buffer.from(authHeader.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString().split(':');
      var username = auth[0];
      var password = auth[1];
    
      User.findOne({username: username})
      .then((user) => {
        if (user === null) {
          var err = new Error('User ' + username + ' does not exist!');
          err.status = 403;
          return next(err);
        }
        else if (user.password !== password) {
          var err = new Error('Your password is incorrect!');
          err.status = 403;
          return next(err);
        }
        else if (user.username === username && user.password === password) {
          req.session.user = 'authenticated';
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
          res.end('You are authenticated!')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => next(err));
    }
    else {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.end('You are already authenticated!');
    }
  })
  
  router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session) {
      req.session.destroy();
      res.clearCookie('session-id');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {
      var err = new Error('You are not logged in!');
      err.status = 403;
      next(err);
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

user model code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    admin:   {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

user route code

```
var express = require('express');
var User = require('../models/user')

var router = express.Router();
router.use(express.json())

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .then((user) => {
      if(user != null) {
        var err = new Error('User ' + req.body.username + ' already exists!');
        err.status = 403;
        next(err);
      }
      else {
        return User.create({
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password});
      }
    })
    .then((user) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({status: 'Registration Successful!', user: user});
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
  
  router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  
    if(!req.session.user) {
      var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
      
      if (!authHeader) {
        var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      }
    
      var auth = new Buffer.from(authHeader.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString().split(':');
      var username = auth[0];
      var password = auth[1];
    
      User.findOne({username: username})
      .then((user) => {
        if (user === null) {
          var err = new Error('User ' + username + ' does not exist!');
          err.status = 403;
          return next(err);
        }
        else if (user.password !== password) {
          var err = new Error('Your password is incorrect!');
          err.status = 403;
          return next(err);
        }
        else if (user.username === username && user.password === password) {
          req.session.user = 'authenticated';
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
          res.end('You are authenticated!')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => next(err));
    }
    else {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.end('You are already authenticated!');
    }
  })
  
  router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session) {
      req.session.destroy();
      res.clearCookie('session-id');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {
      var err = new Error('You are not logged in!');
      err.status = 403;
      next(err);
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please add the request information you are trying to pass to signup api. You can get this from dev tools.

Comment: @Bharat D Bhadresha i am passing  {"username": "sebastian", "password": "password"} to the signup api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was going to localhost:3000/signup when I should have been going to localhost:3000/users/signup.